# error message fix

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    //bool sleected = false;

    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value != null)
    {

        selected.Add(i);
    }

}
//string donew = "";


// line off error 
textBox1.Text = ((String)dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value);
/*  for (int i = 0; i < selected.Count; i++)
{

    textAdded.Add((String)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value);
 //   donew += (String)dataGridView1.Rows[selected[i]].Cells[2].Value;
}*/
```

I keep getting the error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'

What can I do to overcome this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of using

```
textBox1.Text = ((String)dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value);
```

use

```
textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
```

The reason is that you where attempting an explicit cast whereas a cast from double to string does not exist, but fortunately the ToString() method outputs the number as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you could further refine and clean it up with a `foreach` loop. This would make it easier to read in many cases.

Also, as a general practice avoid `textBox1` or `dataGridView1` type names for these objects. Specific naming schemas applied now, prevent needless grief and worry later. It's a good habit to get into as early as possible.

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (r.Cells[3].Value != null)
    {
        selected.Add(r);
    }
}
// line off error 
textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value.ToString()
```